# Get list of values from another workbook (Excel)

Tags: excel

How do I get a list of values across multiple cells from one workbook and display them in another across multiple cells?

I am using Excel for Mac 2011

Thanks

Comment: copy and paste it :D

Comment: Copy and paste does not update the value in the new workbook if it is updated in the other.

Comment: then copy and paste it again.. just kidding :) improve your question and you might get an answer

Comment: About how large is that range? If it were only 10 cells you could reference them by hand

Comment: You might want to look at: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-HP010102338.aspx or Google excel reference data in another workbook

Comment: Oh we are talking about workbooks, not worksheets.